# EVP Interface with AES-NI support

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, evp-cipher

When using the OpenSSL crypto libraries in C/C++, does the EVP interface automatically support AES-NI hardware acceleration (assuming processor support)? Referring to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35036/different-performance-of-openssl-speed-on-the-same-hardware-with-aes-256-evp-an), it appears command-line OpenSSL does have support. I was wondering if there were specific function calls that I had to use to take advantage of this support.

For instance, if I use `EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, type, imp, key, iv)`, do any of these parameters have to specify NI acceleration? I.e. will `EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv)` do the trick?

Thanks!

Comment: The page *you refer to* actually explains that `EVP_` functions automatically detect AES-NI.

Comment: This question triggered a documentation patch in OpenSSL. See [PR 3416: PATCH: EVP_EncryptionInit and AES-NI note](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3416).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When using the OpenSSL crypto libraries in C/C++, does the EVP interface automatically support AES-NI

Yes. `EVP_*` is the official/supported way to ensure AES-NI is used (if available). In fact, EVP is the only way to access hardware acceleration in general.

`EVP_*` is also the only way to obtain other hardware accelerations, like engaging Intel's ia32's SHA acceleration under Skylark; ARM's Crypto extensions available in ARMv8; and VIA's ia32 Padlock extensions on their processors.

Using low level AES routines (like `AES_encrypt` and `AES_decrypt`) are software only-implementations, and they will never use hardware acceleration like AES-NI. Also see Dr. Henson's response on the OpenSSL mailing list at [Verify AES-NI use at runtime?](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Verify-AES-NI-use-at-runtime-td47880.html).

---

Related questions are (1) how to determine if AES-NI is being used; and (2) what are the benchmarking results. For that, see [How can I check if OpenSSL is support/use the Intel AES-NI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25284119)

Comment: As a follow up, does the command line utility `openssl enc` automatically trigger hardware acceleration as well?  

Thanks!

Comment: @MVK_1 - Sorry about the late reply. YES, subcommands like `openssl enc` and `openssl dec` will use AES-NI if its available. Some subcommands need the `-evp` option, like `openssl speed`. Also see [How can I check if OpenSSL is support/use the Intel AES-NI?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25284119)