# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on OS X with fat library

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, openssl

I have build `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` myself from source, specifying `darwin64-x86_64-cc` (for 64-bit) and `darwin-i386-cc` (for 32-bit) to `OpenSSL`'s configure script. 
Created the fat libraries with `lipo` and added them as a dependency in my `Xcode` project.

However, I'am getting an undefined symbol error:

```
undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OPENSSL_ia32cap_P", referenced from:
      _AES_cbc_encrypt in libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

**Note:** Using the same technique works fine for iOS, though.

`lipo -detailed_info libcrypto.a` reveals:

```
Fat header in: libcrypto.a
fat_magic 0xcafebabe
nfat_arch 2
architecture i386
    cputype CPU_TYPE_I386
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_I386_ALL
    offset 48
    size 2700624
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture x86_64
    cputype CPU_TYPE_X86_64
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_X86_64_ALL
    offset 2700672
    size 3938432
    align 2^2 (4)
```

Comment: Do you have the header files for those libraries installed?  Often there is a binaries package distro, which just has libraries, and a separate devel package for libraries and associated headers for coding against the libraries.

Comment: I've included the correct headers.

Comment: The headers are slightly different for i386 and x86_64. While the fat library builds correctly (or combines correctly with `lipo`), the headers will be slightly off for all but one of the slices. But Petesh is right. I seem to recall that's exported in some case (like static archive), but not others (like shared object). The issue is mentioned at [How can I check if OpenSSL is suport/use the Intel AES-NI?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25284119)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks to be a bug in the code generator for x64 in the static library case.

The easiest, non patch openssl change workaround is to add a reference to `OPENSSL_cleanse` somewhere in your code, even if it's not used. That will fix up the link-time reference.

What's actually happening is that the symbol is being referenced in some assembly code.

The assembly code simply says that `_OPENSSL_ia32cap_P` is an extern symbol, without making the cross-link to state that it needs to be linked in. This works for `libcrypto.dylib` because the reference is resolved when generating the `.dylib` file; however the reference is never resolved in the `.a` case because the only code that actually contains the symbol is `x86_64cpuid.o`, which only gets linked in if you use any of the routines provided by that `.o`.

Symbols in this file includes `OPENSSL_cleanse`, so if you reference this routine, the link works.

Comment: Here's what using your advice I ended up doing:
`extern int OPENSSL_cleanse(void *ptr, size_t len);`

Comment: And somewhere arbitrary in the code: `OPENSSL_cleanse(nil, 0);`

Comment: I encountered similar issue when compiled libevent. I added OPENSSL_cleanse to the code but failed to fix it , at last I add  x86_64cpuid.o path to relative Makefile to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same linker error, and I also tried adding the line `extern int OPENSSL_cleanse(void *ptr, size_t len);` without success.

What ended up working for me was adding the following line, anywhere in your code files:

```cpp
uint32_t OPENSSL_ia32cap_P[4] = { 0 };
```

Also, I used the following link as reference: https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/517073cd4b/crypto/cpu-intel.c#76