# OpenSSL library linker command failed: ("_OPENSSL_ia32cap_P") in AES decoding

Tags: openssl, aes

Using OpenSSL AES encrypting. Library connected well, rsa commands works well.
When i use AES cant reach methods from libcrypto.a.(But when i use RSA methods in code, aes works well. No RSA -> no AES)

Error is:
*Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OPENSSL_ia32cap_P", referenced from:
      _AES_cbc_encrypt in libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

PS. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943977/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-on-os-x-with-fat-library) topic doesn't help

Comment: What is your link command? `OPENSSL_ia32cap_P` has public visibility in `libcrypto.a`. However, it is private in `libcrypto.so`.

Comment: Now _OPENSSL_cleanse(NULL, 0);_ put anywhere works stable. Before it was some other mistakes and OPENSSL_cleanse didn't help.After I fix all other errors its became stable.

Comment: I also had this problem on macOS, the solution on my side was to make sure my OTHER_LDFLAGS had `-lssl` and `-lcrypto` before any `-framework` argument.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same linker error, and I also tried adding the line `extern int OPENSSL_cleanse(void *ptr, size_t len);` as mentioned on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943977/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-on-os-x-with-fat-library), without success.

What ended up working for me was adding the following line, anywhere in your code files:

```cpp
uint32_t OPENSSL_ia32cap_P[4] = { 0 };
```

Also, I used the following link as reference: https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/517073cd4b/crypto/cpu-intel.c#76