# C: error when linking with OpenSSL library dynamically

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, openssl

I have a C program, which is using AES routines from the OpenSSL library.
I have the necessary library installed (`libssl-dev`)

I can compile my program statically:

```
gcc -s -o aes aes.c /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
```

but when i try to compile it dynamically, I get following error:

```
$ gcc -s -o aes aes.c -lcrypto
/tmp/ccofFr4N.o: In function `encrypt':
aes.c:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `aesni_set_encrypt_key'
aes.c:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `aesni_cbc_encrypt'
aes.c:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `aesni_cbc_encrypt'
/tmp/ccofFr4N.o: In function `decrypt':
aes.c:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `aesni_set_decrypt_key'
aes.c:(.text+0x31e): undefined reference to `aesni_cbc_encrypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why can't I compile my program with OpenSSL linked dynamically ?

**UPDATE**

So, here are the libraries from `libssl-dev`:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

I noticed the following. When I grep them for the name of the `AES` function, only `libcrypto.a` matches.

```
$ grep aesni_set_encrypt_key /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.*
Binary file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a matches
```

Shouldn't `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so` contain these functions as well ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some unrelated/old libcrypto.so somewhere in the search path? What happens if you say `nm -D /usr/lib/libcrypto.so | grep aesni_set_decrypt_key` (or where are your 64-bit libraries stored)?

Comment: @n.m. - `nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so | grep aesni` does not show nothing.

Comment: Does your code use those undefined functions directly?

Comment: @Ian Abbott - yes, I am calling those functions directly in my code, ie: `aesni_cbc_encrypt(buffer, buffer, len, &aes_ks3, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);`.

Comment: @MartinVegter - aren't you supposed to use `AES_cbc_encrypt`, etc.?

Comment: @Ian Abbott -  `AES_cbc_encrypt` is 5 times slower, because it is not using the `AES_NI` instructions of my CPU. See my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993514/program-linked-with-lcrypto-is-many-times-slower-than-openssl-command).

Comment: @MartinVegter - in that case, perhaps you should be using the EVP functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption).

Comment: Are you sure `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a` is the correct library to link?

Comment: @Deleisha - I am sure the program compiled using `gcc -s -o aes aes.c /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a` works properly. The only problem is, that being statically linked, it is rather large.

Comment: On my system, `nm -D /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so | fgrep aesni` prints all AES NI symbols as defined. It's an old system with libcrypto.so.0.9.8. I imagine newer versions should have them too. Are you sure your libcrypt.so really belongs to libssl-dev and its version corresponds to libcrypto.a?

Comment: `https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2503&user=guest&pass=guest` could this be the issue

Answer (score 0):

most likely the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` is not part of the compiler search path.

Suggest, before the `-lcrypto` to insert the parameter: `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Comment: unfortunately, this does not help. I still get the same error. Besides, see my update. It looks as if the functions were not exported by the libcrypto shared library.