# apache webserver testing with and without aesni enabled

Tags: apache, openssl, webserver, aes

I am trying to test https behavior with apachebenchmark(ab) and I want to repeat the tests with and without aes-ni enabled. When I issue following commands, I do see that aes-ni is enabled on my systems (one acting as server and other as client).

```
OPENSSL_ia32cap="~0x200000200000000" openssl speed -elapsed -evp aes-128-cbc

type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes

aes-128-cbc     255813.58k   277299.88k   282401.71k   284642.99k   283273.90k

openssl speed -elapsed -evp aes-128-cbc

type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes

aes-128-cbc     547335.98k   588501.72k   601244.50k   599078.23k   600743.94k
```

But when I issue below commands, I do not see any difference. What am I missing?

1) `env OPENSSL_ia32cap="~0x200000200000000" time ab -k -n 10000 https://172.31.18.179/index8192.html`

2) `time ab -k -n 10000 https://172.31.18.179/index8192.html`

where `index8192.html` is a file of size 8192 bytes.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Also see [How can I check if OpenSSL is support/use the Intel AES-NI?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25284119) I believe there are some instructions for using the `openssl speed` command.